# Removing Fedora15 and install Fedora17

Tags: linux, installation, fedora-15, fedora-17

I have a DELLE6420 with dual boot of Linux Fedora15 and Windows7. I wish to install Fedora17 in place of Fedora15. I understand that i have to retain the /home folder. As for system-wide installation, i have configured Apache, mysqladmin etc for my web development purposes. All my web related folders are in /var/www/html. In fact, the issue is that it is my employer's IT department that will handle the installation. It is me who has to tell beforehand what to do and what not to do.
What other things should i be aware of so that i do not have unpleasant surprises?

Comment: It's not a bad idea to make a full backup, maybe an image of all the partitions. Better safe than sorry. You should also make a manual to keep track of everything related to installations and configuration procedures, as well as some version control system for your working files, so, you just need to worry about your personal files, if they aren't synced to some external backup like a cloud storage service.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing F15 and installing F17, upgrade from F15 to F17.  This keeps all of your settings, users, services, and user data.

This will work as long as F17 is still supported, which should be for at least six more months.  (If you let it go beyond the support lifetime of F17, you will not be able to upgrade from F15 and will need to reinstall.)

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrade?rd=PreUpgrade

I recently did this, from F15 to F17.  It took a few hours, but it was almost hands-off.  Very slick.

Backing up your system is still recommended.

Comment: I had a disastrous experience when doing an upgrade last time. It broke many things including my NVIDIA drivers :) So the IT dept forbids doing that :)

Comment: It is guaranteed that removing F15 will break everything.  But rules are rules, I suppose.